# Using ContinuumNavigationTransition in WP8.1

Tags: xaml, animation, windows-phone-8.1

I'm having difficulties understanding how to use some animations in Windows Phone 8.1. I have a ListView with an ItemTemplate that I would like to animate the same way that the Messages app is animated when transitioning from the messages list to a conversation.
So when tapping an item in my ListView, I would like to animate an inner TextBlock (it kind of flies away to the bottom of the page), then the details page shows and the title flies back in the new page from the top right (it's the same text).

I set `ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo.IsEntranceElement` (on the target page), `ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo.IsExitElement` and `ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo.ExitElementContainer` (on the source page) but it doesn't work. I also read about the `Transitions` dependance property to set on the target page but it doesn't work either.

So how am I supposed to do if I want to get the same animation as there is on transitioning from the conversations list to a conversation details on the Messages app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this kind of animation, so I'll post the XAML you need. You can check where yours is different from mine:

Source page:

```
<ListView ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo.ExitElementContainer="True">
<!-- XAML stuff -->
<TextBlock ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo.IsExitElement="True" />
<!-- XAML stuff -->
</ListView>
```

Target Page:

```
<Page.Transitions>
    <TransitionCollection>
        <NavigationThemeTransition>
            <NavigationThemeTransition.DefaultNavigationTransitionInfo>
                <ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo/>
            </NavigationThemeTransition.DefaultNavigationTransitionInfo>
        </NavigationThemeTransition>
    </TransitionCollection>
</Page.Transitions>

<!-- bla-bla -->
<TextBlock ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo.IsEntranceElement="True"/>
<!-- other code -->
```

Comment: Ok I see my problem. The Transitions DP I set was the one of another container than Page. That makes sense, now. Thank you very much!